# Windows Explorer - Different Behaviour for Double-Click of Files and Folders

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, double-click

I want to have a different behavior for double-click in Windows Explorer (Windows 7) for folders and files.

Folders should be opened with double-click, but neither documents nor executables should be opened by double-click. Last ones should only be opened using the context menu or, additionally, if possible using e.g. STRG+Click or ALT+Click.

The only options regarding click behavior in Windows is single-click or double-click to open an item is in the Explorer -> "Folder Options" -> "General". This is not what I need.

Is there a registry-key I can configure or some other possibility to realize this behavior?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such functionality to change mouse behaviour for files v/s folders atleast in Windows.

Comment: That would be a shame.

Answer (score 0):

**Ugly workaround:**

Windows only opens files if there is a file-association defined. For unknown file-associations a window asking for a program to choose is shown. So you can add a "donothing-script" as file-association for every file-type...

Example (disable perl from executing):

```
ASSOC .pl=Perl
FTYPE Perl=donothing.exe
```

if you don't know how to write a `donothing.exe` then use something like this

```
FTYPE Perl=wscript C:\path\to\empty-file.vbs %*
```

To see what extensions are registered, call `assoc` without arguments.
See also `assoc /?` and `ftype /?`